# Static block in web service handler

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws web service with several handlers. I have a particular object that is performance wise costly to initiate. I need this object to process each and every request come to web service.

Is it a solution to put this object to a static block? Since static block is created at class loading time will it give a performance improvement. But still does it achieve what I need. I need same object kept in the memory and reused for all requests. But as I know in a web service each request is allocated to a thread object in the static block will not be shared by threads. it is?

Expecting a bit of explanation here guys.

Thank you

Comment: Static variables are shared by threads. However, they are not necessarily thread safe. If your object is thread safe, this might be an option.

Comment: It is a read only object. But static blocks are not shared with in thread. is it or is it not?

Answer (score 2):

A static block is a piece of code which is run once when the class is initialized by the class loader. You might use it to set up your complex object and then keep a reference to it in a static variable like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final LanguageLookup languageLookup;

    static {
        languageLookup = new LanguageLookup ();
        languageLookup.loadData();
    }

    public Response handleRequest(Request request) {
        String language = languageLookup.lookup(request.getCountryCode());
        response.setLanguage(language);
        return response;
    }
}
```

If you do this in a multi-threaded environment like a servlet or a webservice you need to be sure that the state of LanguageLookup cannot change after its initialization. If it uses dependencies of its own for operations other than its initialization, these must also be stateless.

I think it is generally not a good idea to do it this way because you are hard-wiring your class to the LanguageLookup, making it tightly coupled and harder to unit test.

It is very easy to use a dependency injection framework like Spring to set up [singletons](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes):

> When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will
>   be managed and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that
>   bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being
>   returned.

In the application context you would have something like:

```
<bean name="languageLookup" class="com.acme.foo.LanguageLookup" singleton="true" init-method="loadData"/>
```

And in your code:

```
public class MyClass {

    private LanguageLookup languageLookup;

    public Response handleRequest(Request request) {
        String language = languageLookup.lookup(request.getCountryCode());
        response.setLanguage(language);
        return response;
    }

    // called by Spring
    public void setLanguageLookup(LanguageLookup languageLookup) {
        this.languageLookup = languageLookup;
    }
}
```